# Removing escapechars from my string, but when i try to break my csv apart it persists breaking the string in excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

so i have the following code

```
new_action = []
my_dict = {10:'breakchar'}
# Insira nessa dict o char poluidor

for i in df['Action']:
    try:
        z = i.translate(my_dict)
        new_action.append(z)
    except:
        new_action.append(0)

new_action = np.array(new_action)
df['NewAction'] = new_action.tolist()
df.columns
```

It has the responsibility of substituting every \n escape char into a 'breakline' string.
But when i check if it worked in excel. It results in this

[image]

It substitutes the breakchar but excel keeps breaking the line after i open my csv archive, would appreciate a few inputs on the why?

Comment: For one, open it in notepad or similar so you can see what's actually happening instead of trying to backwards engineer whatever stupid decisions excel made under the hood for interpreting your CSV into an excel spreadsheet. A program like Notepad++ or vim or similar can show line breaks, carriage returns, and other whitespace which may lead you to a solution. For instance, you may still have `\r` carriage returns (I think `char(10)` in excel formula language) that you aren't replacing that will still cause a line to break in windows.

Comment: It seens they already break before i even open up the file. I tried opening in notepad ++ and it mantains. I checked for other escape character but i got nada.

Comment: But i tested out ur theory of the \r character theory and it worked, if u want to answer it i will give it to u. But the notebook part also bugged out.

Answer (score 0):

```
new_action = []
my_dict = {10:'(new line)',13 : "(carriage ret)"}
# Insira nessa dict o char poluidor

for i in df['Action']:
    try:
        z = i.translate(my_dict)
        new_action.append(z)
    except:
        new_action.append(0)

new_action = np.array(new_action)
df['NewAction'] = new_action.tolist()
df.columns
```

Manage to find out the extra skipable character